# How to deallocate android resources

Tags: android, android-resources

How can I deallocate the memory of android resources like `TextView`, `ImageView` etc inside the `onDestroy()` method because they are consuming memory and tell me how to release memory.

Comment: job of garbage collector to free memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage Collector will release resources for you.

Just make sure you are not holding references that are no more required.

You can try setting your references to null in onDestroy() call back method.

Also, you can use Memory Analyzer Tool to investigate further.